# How do I copy MySQL databases to another Ubuntu machine?

Tags: mysql, lamp, database

I installed a LAMP server on my pc and created databases. Now I want to copy it to my friend's computer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. To backup/save databases as SQL files, run

   ```
   mysqldump -uroot -p database_name > dumpfilename.sql
   ```

   Replace `database_name` with the name of the database you want to copy over and enter the root password when asked.
2. Copy the `dumpfilename.sql` file over to the other system like any other regular file and import the database using this command:

   ```
   mysql -uroot -p database_name < dumpfilename.sql
   ```

   Again, replace `database_name` with the (new) name of the database and enter the root password when asked.

Note that this is totally not OS-specific, but a general way of dumping/importing MySQL databases.